# How to generate a blocking storage queue

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I know what I want to do, and I know what I want the calls to look like, but I DONT know what structure I should use to accomplish this.

I think i have an idea though, but Im looking for more input.

here's the scenario: Android application: IRC Client.

Trying to setup the socket reading loop between a service (working) and the ui (also working).

What I WANT to do, is run a reading thread inside the service that attaches to the reader and adds lines to a queue of some sort.  I want the UI to call a method exposed by the service that dequeues a line from the queue, (and heres the important bit), *blocks* if there is no data in the queue.  Why would I want to do a thing like that?  Because the UI is *also* running its reader in a thread.  So I have one thread running the reader inside the service and adding lines to the queue, and another thread running in the UI reading from the queue. (note: neither of these is the actual main ui thread)

The two threads and the way to run them I have down just fine, I just dont know what structure to use to store the data, or How to implement it.  Does `BlockingQueue` do what I need, or am I misunderstanding it entirely?  If not that, then what type of collection should I use, and how do I implement the blocking for the UI portion so that it sits and waits for more input if the queue is empty?

Comment: Yes, BlockingQueue's take() is what you want.

Comment: Well...that was easy.  The morass of obfuscated SDK that I was digging through didn't quite explain exactly what that thing did.  Thanks

Comment: Javadoc is your friend: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html#take()